# Loop through table1, extract information from table2 and insert into table3 in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm new to control structure in SQL and I'm trying to loop through a table with customer and date information and based on the date column, find the sales for that customer in the next 7 days and insert it into another table. Here is what I have so far, but I don't think the set statement work with select:

```sql
create procedure proc()
   for cust_cursor as cc cursor for 
       select customer, date_dt from table1
   do
       set sales = (
             select sum(sales_amt) from table2 
             where customer = cust_cursor.customer and date_dt between cust_cursor.date_dt and (interval '7' day + cust_cursor.date_dt)
                   )
       insert into table3 values (cust_cursor.customer, sales)
   end for;

call proc();
```

Comment: Note that "loop through" should usually be converted to just "JOIN". But to address your specific issue, use `SELECT INTO` not `SET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fred's comment at full length :-)

*But to address your specific issue, use SELECT INTO not SET*

```
   do
         select sum(sales_amt) INTO sales from table2 
         where customer = cust_cursor.customer and date_dt between cust_cursor.date_dt and (interval '7' day + cust_cursor.date_dt)
```

*Note that "loop through" should usually be converted to just "JOIN".*

```
insert into table3 (cust_cursor.customer, sales)
select t1.customer, sum(t2.sales_amt) 
from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
  on t2.customer = t1.customer
 and t2.date_dt between t1.date_dt and (interval '7' day + t1.date_dt)
;
```

Look ma, no loop, no proc, much more efficient.